# Using ARReferenceImage with ARKit in iOS 11.3 beta 2 results in "error: Exception while running actool:"

Tags: ios, arkit, xcode9.3-beta

Repro:

- Xcode 9.3 beta
- iOS 11.3 beta 2
- Add ARReferenceImages to Assets.xcassets following documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience)
- Compile

Results in:
error: Exception while running actool: ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Xcode where the deployment target also has to be 11.3 to use ARReferenceImages with asset catalogs.

Fix: Change deployment target to 11.3

Comment: If it looks like a bug, did you [report it](http://bugreport.apple.com)?

Comment: Filed a bug report! @rickster https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=39142400

Comment: hahaha I spent all day yesterday trying to fix this , thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Adding a Named color (New color set) to the asset catalog will workaround this error.